# how can I get clipboard copy events from Mac OS X to carry over into Oracle VM Arch w/ i3 window manager?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, archlinux

I am running arch linux with Oracle VM Virtual Box Manager on Mac OS X 10.7, and am running into a problem where I cannot select text in my Mac OS X world and paste it into Arch land...  I tried installing a program called KeyRemap4MacBook and enabled Mouse Keys Mode -> [option] Space to MiddleClick...

When I try copying some text from either Mac OS X or from within the terminal inside the i3 window manager, pressing option-space does absolutely nothing.

Comment: I havent actually used virtualbox but sometimes there is a send/get clipboard command. I usually see it in VNC or remote X clients but if i remember right you used to have to do it for VirtualPC too... so maybe check that out.

Comment: is there a keyboard modifier that lets me get the middle mouse button?  Like option + click or something?

Comment: im not sure i never use more than 2 buttons :-) i know control+click is right click so maybe try option+click or option+control+click...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you installed the [guest additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) in your arch linux VM? I believe bi-directional clipboard won't work without them.

If you find that you are often needing to share the clipboard, you might find more success by launching your VM in a headless mode (see `VBoxHeadless` or the `--type headless` in [chapter 7](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch07.html#vboxheadless) of the manual. You can then use something like `TightVNC` to connect directly to the guest and `autocutsel` to get a shared clipboard through the VNC connection.